# Importing csv with "." characters within data

Tags: phpmyadmin

When column lengths are calculated, it seems like dot characters within strings are not counted therefore I get the "data too long" error. When I replace dots with commas, import works fine. Data is decimals with nulls allowed. I have tried comma and tab as delimiter, fields wrapped and not. Nothing changes the result. Removing null records allows to import as decimals but with nulls, it is automatically tried to be parsed as varchar with length one character short.

Sample csv (tab delimited, first row header (Column A), three rows of data, second row null):

```
Column A
3.14

3.14
```

I can reproduce this on the demo server. There is also the following, which might be related:
https://github.com/phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin/issues/13292

Comment: Could you add a sample of your data?

Comment: Added the sample data.